# openGL VP matrix issue?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

All,
I have been following this OpenGL texturing tutorial [here](https://www.3dgep.com/texturing-and-lighting-with-opengl-and-glsl/#comment-61486) in order to render a texture mapped earth sphere using GLSL 1.2.  You can download the source.  But I am not able to run the example code.  It requires a later version of OpenGL and GLSL than what my workbook supports (late 2016 with Iris GPU).  Note that I am using glew, glut, and soil; but am using my own math library in place of glm.

The issue:
The same texture maps right to left, instead of left to right.  Sure, it's easy to say: just set u=1-u in the frag shader.  But, that's not the fundamental issue; which is what I'm interested in understanding.  I will have multiple cameras on many more objects than a few celestial bodies.  All cameras must be observing the same world.  And I fear that any lack of understanding of how the cameras are setup will create more rework than original work.

Upon second pass, I was suspicious of the view and projection matrices.  I believe the view matrix is generated the same way as gluLookAt() (which I believe sets up the view matrix as a right handed matrix).  I believe the projection matrix is generated in right-handed coordinates as well.  I have been right-hand biased because I read that prior to some version past OpenGL 2.1, there is no concept of NDC, and that OpenGL is right-handed in MVP space.

Without further ado, here's my LookAt:

```
void Matrix4d::LookAtRH(const Vector3d &eye, const Vector3d &center, const Vector3d &zenith) {
//functionally equivilent to gluLookAt()
//https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GluLookAt_code
Vector3d _look(center);
Vector3d forward(_look - eye);
forward.Normalize();

Vector3d right(forward);
right.Cross(zenith);
right.Normalize();

Vector3d up(right);
up.Cross(forward);

//rotate
m[0] = right.x;     m[1] = up.x;        m[2] = -forward.x;  m[3] = 0;
m[4] = right.y;     m[5] = up.y;        m[6] = -forward.y;  m[7] = 0;
m[8] = right.z;     m[9] = up.z;        m[10] = -forward.z; m[11] = 0;
m[12] = 0;          m[13] = 0;           m[14] = 0;          m[15] = 1;

Translate(-eye.x, -eye.y, -eye.z);
}

void Matrix4d::Translate(double x, double y, double z) {
m[12] = m[0] * x + m[4] * y + m[8] * z + m[12];
m[13] = m[1] * x + m[5] * y + m[9] * z + m[13];
m[14] = m[2] * x + m[6] * y + m[10] * z + m[14];
m[15] = m[3] * x + m[7] * y + m[11] * z + m[15];
}
```

Here's my projection matrix calculation:

```
void Matrix4d::ProjectionViewRH(double fov_degrees, double aspectRatio, double near, double far) {
//https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/graphics/perspective-projections-in-lh-and-rh-systems-r3598/
double fov_radians = PI / 180.0 * fov_degrees;
double yScale = 1.0 / tan(fov_radians / 2.0);
double xScale = yScale / aspectRatio;
double nearToFar = far - near;

m[0] = (double)xScale;  
m[1] = 0;
m[2] = 0;
m[3] = 0;

m[4] = 0;
m[5] = (double)yScale;
m[6] = 0;
m[7] = 0;

m[8] = 0;
m[9] = 0;
m[10] = -(double)( (far + near) / nearToFar);
m[11] = -1;

m[12] = 0;
m[13] = 0;
m[14] = -(double)(2.0 * far*near / nearToFar);
m[15] = 0;
}
```

Can anyone deny these are correct for an OpenGL 2.1 environment? Am I missing something entirely?!

For the sake of completion:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

glutInitContextVersion(2, 1);
glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE | GLUT_DEBUG);

glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW1_SIZE_X, WINDOW1_SIZE_Y); //optional
glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);//optional
glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS);
mainWindow = glutCreateWindow("Hello World");
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glutSetOption(GLUT_RENDERING_CONTEXT, GLUT_USE_CURRENT_CONTEXT);

subwindows[0] = glutCreateSubWindow(mainWindow, 0, 0, earthWindowDimensions[0], earthWindowDimensions[1]);
glutDisplayFunc(renderScene1);
glutIdleFunc(idleCallback1);

glutMouseWheelFunc(mouseWheelCallback1);
glutMouseFunc(mouseCallback1);
glutMotionFunc(motionCallback1);
motionCallback1(0, 0);
glutIdleFunc(idleCallback1);
    …
}
```

Here's the flow of the render callback:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glutSetWindow(mainWindow);
//glViewport(0, 0, mainWindowDimensions[0], mainWindowDimensions[1]);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glutSwapBuffers();

glutSetWindow(subwindows[0]);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
scene.DrawScene();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

vert shader:

```
void main(void) {
//pass these to fragment shader
NormalDir_World_f = (ModelMatrix * vec4(VertNormal_modelSpace, 0.0)).xyz; //0 in w component because normal is only a direction
ViewDir_World_f = -Eye_worldSpace;
LightPos_World_f = LightPosition_worldSpace;

AmbientColor_f = AmbientColor;
DiffuseColor_f = DiffuseColor;
SpecularColor_f = SpecularColor;
LightColor_f = LightColor;

texCoords_v2f = texCoords;

gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertPosition_modelSpace, 1.0);
}
```

frag shader:

```
void main(void) {

vec3 N = normalize(NormalDir_World_f);
vec3 E = normalize(ViewDir_World_f);
vec3 L = normalize(LightPos_World_f);

float cosTheta = dot(L,N);
vec3 diffuse = DiffuseColor_f * (LightColor_f * max(0.0, cosTheta));

vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);
vec3 V = normalize(-E);
float cosAlpha = dot(R, V);

vec3 specular = step(0.0, cosTheta) * (SpecularColor_f * (LightColor_f * pow(max(0.0, cosAlpha), 50.0) ));
//dont divide distance^2 here so light appears consistent regardless of model transforms

gl_FragColor = vec4(AmbientColor_f + diffuse + specular, 1.0) * texture2D(diffuseSampler, texCoords_v2f);
 }
```

These shaders were adapted from some old GLES stuffs that worked fine.  So, don't spend much time there.

Comment: Every intel Iris GPU supports at least GL 4.3, the original example uses 3.3 core. It is totally unclear why you had issues running it, bnut the actual GPU is none of them. Now you're asking for a forward compatible 2.1 debug context, which simply doesn't exist. You'll end up with some unspecified legacy context that way.

Comment: The statmenet "[because I read] that prior to some version past OpenGL 2.1, there is no concept of NDC, and that OpenGL is right-handed in MVP space." is not true. NDC was there right from the beginning, and the handedness of coordinate spaces in the GL was _never_ enforced. Legacy GL did have some default conventions in mind when using some of the convenience functions, and those conventions were right-handed object, world and eye space, but left-handed NDC and window space. The standard projection matrices from `glOrtho`, `glFrustum`, `gluPerspective` did include a flip along z.

Comment: I find your matrices calculations right. Now the question is how you pass them to the shaders, it's a matter of you use `double` while the shader uses `float`

Comment: @Ripi2.  The matrices are converted to GLfloat before passing.

Comment: I "answered" part of your question. The rest, it isn't clear to me what you're asking. Texture coordinates? Several view ports, one for each camera?

Comment: @derhass Can we not get hung up on the hypothetical, and focus on the issue at hand in OpenGL 2.1?  I didn't ask to run the tutorial code.

Comment: @Ripi Thank you.  If the matrix calculations are correct, I have no explanation as to why east points west on the texture mapped earth I'm rendering.  This is what I hope to understand.  Sorry I wasn't clear.  I was certain the discrepancy between my code and the example had to be in the view or projection matrices.  Perhaps there's something more going on there that I'm not aware of.